# community wiki question - desired result?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

When there is a community wiki question such as this one, what is the desired result?: [When do we say "Alenu L'shabe'ach"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4229/when-do-we-say-alenu-lshabeach)

Do we want all the people answering to edit the question and put the answers in the question itself? Or do we still want individual answers to the question? If the latter, what do we gain out of marking it as "community wiki"?

Answer (score 2):

Making the question "community wiki" allows more people to edit the question. You might do this if you want people to add examples of an issue, for example. Answers should still be entered as such.

In the case you cite, it probably would have been more appropriate for the asker to post an answer with the starting list in it and make the *answer* a community wiki.

Comment: Well, it's never too late, right?

Answer (score 2):

In such a case (where the answers form a list but there's no particular reason the community has to be able to edit the question itself), I generally, though perhaps mistakenly, understand the asker's intent to be that he thinks of all answers as equally correct if correct at all, and members of one big, correct list. Thus, none should be accepted as correct to the exclusion of the others. Marking the question "community wiki" both prevents the accepted answer (if any) from getting accepted-answer reputation and prevents the asker's "accepted answer rate" from going down if he doesn't accept any answer.

Answer (score 2):

We have provided some additional guidance at the blog:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

TL;DR version

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly, and only in very specific circumstances.